# why does sails.js crash after I restart my computer

Tags: node.js, sails.js, sails.io.js

I am new when it comes to using sail.js.

I installed Sail.js and then using **sails lift** I started the app it went well.

after sometime, I switched of my laptop, just to turn it on back I then an error.
It won't start.

I created a new project in another folder it worked well.
I switched off my laptop and switched it on again, and i get the same error.

Please What is really happening.

here is the error

C:\emmsdan\main\mws-looper-two\node_modules\machine\lib\Machine.prototype.exec.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { MZP

```
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\emmsdan\main\mws-looper-two\node_modules\machine\lib\Machine.constructor.js:149:26)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\emmsdan\main\mws-looper-two\node_modules\machine\index.js:1:80)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
```

Comment: You have a syntax error somewhere in your code.

Comment: i did'nt write the code. one of sails dependencies i think.

Comment: Did you try killing the server 'control + c' and then re-lifting?

Comment: @Raqem I did. i uninstalled the package and reinstalled it again and i get the same issues.

Comment: Have you tried a clean uninstall / reinstall of npm and sails to rule out a corrupt installation issue?

Steps to do so:

`sudo npm cache clean -f`    
`sudo npm install -g n`   
`sudo n stable`   
`sudo npm install sails -g`